# Common references in node/create-react-app monorepo

Tags: typescript, create-react-app

I have a monorepo like follows (also a `server` folder in there but trying to only get it working with the client first). I want to import members from dto.ts into App.tsx

```
├── client
│   ├── package.json
│   ├── src
│   │   └── App.tsx
│   └── tsconfig.json
└── common
   ├── dto.ts
   ├── index.ts
   └── tsconfig.json
```

my `tsconf.json` in common is like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true, 
    "declarationMap": true,
    "rootDir": ".",   
    "composite": true  
  },
  "references": [] 
}
```

my `tsconf.json` in client is like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
     ...
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../common"
    }
  ],
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

I try to import it into App.tsx it like so:

import { dto } from "../../common";

but i get the following error:

```
Module not found: You attempted to import ../../common which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

I don't want to eject or anything like that. I want a really simple solution to do this, but I've been looking for hours and I can't seem to find one. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a local npm package in common, giving it a name in `package.json`, and installing it like so in both client and server:

```
npm i ../common/
```

I can import types/etc like so:

```
import { foo } from "common";
```

A bit fiddly setting up typescript etc, but works really well now! Exactly what I wanted.